# CURL PUT request to a restful API

Tags: bash, api

I have a an API that i am using to perform some automation for some thin client devices.  What I am attempting to do is to update a field in a database from the API with information provided by the device.

I have tested the server side code with Postman and the field updates as expected but I cannot get the curl request to run correctly.  I did try the code that postman generates for curl requests and that failed.

I am running this from a bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)
IP=$(hostname -I)
FQDN=$(hostname -A)

echo $MAC
echo $IP
echo $FQDN
echo " "

curl -X PUT --header "application/json" --header "charset=utf-8"  --header "content-length: 4" --header "application/json" http://ttuc-thinman1.tuc.us.ray.com/api/ThinClient?mac=$MAC&ip=$IP&fqdn=$FQDN
```

When I attempt to run this code it dumps straight back to the prompt with no info.

What am I a doing wrong?

Comment: Please check your shebang. First of all, there should not be a space after ! and are you sure you have a bash on a machine you are running it on. Maybe you have just sh.

Comment: yes, it has bash, I have other scripts that are running correctly with that shebang.  For this purpose I will change that and test

Comment: So does `echo $MAC` work? Your desc is a little unclear, if `echo` not work too, just delete the the `curl sentence` to narrow down the issue, it has none business with api call. If `echo` work, you said no info is not correct.

Comment: I guess it's your headers, try `curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://...`

Comment: Apologies for the delay. This is what I am sending:

curl  -X PUT -H 'ContentType: application/json' -H 'charset: UTF8' -H 'Content-Length: 4' http://my-server/api/ThinClient?mac=12_34_56_78_90_11&fqdn=the.path.to.my.device

I have also tried curl  -X PUT -H 'ContentType: application/json' -H 'charset: UTF8' -H 'Content-Length: 4' http://my-server/api/ThinClient?mac=12_34_56_78_90_11&fqdn=the-path-to-my-device